# event contex for live function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI ,

I am using JQuery 1.3 , I am facing problem in using `live` event as in jQuery `DOM` element "context" is bound to default document root. So how to overcome such thing?

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, live events can be bound to a DOM element "context"
>   rather than to the default document root. To set this context, we use the
>   jQuery()  function's second argument, passing in a single DOM element (as
>   opposed to a jQuery collection or a selector).

Answer (score 1):

Either upgrade to 1.4, or write a plugin that provides a context with live events. Copy the source from [jQuery 1.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) for that plugin if need be.

Comment: i dont know what part to copy ?, can u please help me in that

Comment: Search for the line that contains `jQuery.each(["live", "die"]`. That is where `live` is being defined in 1.4.2. Pay close attention to the use of `context` variable in it. Start tracing from there.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 1.4.2 and use `$('#foo', '#bar').live()`.

Comment: Well , i have restriction not to upgrade and if i do use this in jquery 1.3 then whenever i will clone the HTML Block then newly cloned block would failed to receive event - even i am changing the class name for newly cloned block.